# Getting Tensorboard Profiler to run in Windows

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I am having trouble getting Tensorboard Profiler to run on my windows machine. I am using the `tf.profiler` progrtammatic mode as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#profiler_tools):

```
tf.profiler.experimental.start('logdir')
# Train the model here
tf.profiler.experimental.stop()
```

I then ran TB from the terminal as such:

```
tensorboard --logdir=<path> --host localhost --port 6006
```

However when I open the profiler tab I see this:

[image]

I suspect this is because I am training on Windows and the instructions are made for Linux. For example, insuring CUPTI exists on path (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#install_the_profiler_and_gpu_prerequisites)). Has anyone got profiler to work on Windows? If so, where there any nuances to the installation beyond simply `pip install tensorboard_plugin_profile`?